# Android Google API key

Tags: android, google-api, google-signin

I have created android project which allows authentication through Google API. I have followed [this](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating#prerequisites) tutorial.

Everything works fine on my laptop. When I imported the project into my other machine I get `handleSignInResult:false` error. I belive this is because of `google-services.json` file which I generated for my other machine's SHA-1.

How can I re-generate this file (if this is my problem) for my other machine with the same project? When I open `Google Developers enable Google service for your app` I am unable to provide different SHA-1 key

Comment: does this help? http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2016/03/registering-oauth-clients-for-google.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution by experimenting with different settings.

What I had to do is not only to add another SHA-1 to API keys but also create new OAuth 2.0 client ID for machine with different SHA-1. After that I went back to generating json file and this time there was both SHA-1 keys present. I have downloaded new google-services.json file and replaced the old one. Works like charm

Answer (score 0):

Because SHA-1 key will change for each system, so you need to replace with current system SHA-1 key in google developer account to run your application. Once the apk is generated it will run in all the devices.

Comment: I need to test the application so geenrating app and changing SHA-1 is not an option